How to pass data & open a Modal using dynamically mapped pressable Card component in NextUI
I have a list of images to display thumbnails. On top of that, for each image, I want to click it to show the image on the full size.
To achieve this, I use Modal and useDisclosure() from  @nextui-org/react. Below is my code:
const { isOpen, onOpen, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure();

<Card className="" isPressable onPress={onOpen}>
    <CardHeader className="flex-col items-start">
        <p className="text-tiny uppercase font-bold">id:12345678</p>
        <small className="text-default-500">date:2024-01</small>
        <h4 className="font-bold text-large">name</h4>
    </CardHeader>
    <CardBody className="overflow-visible">
        {/* <a href="https://www.baidu.com" target="_blank"> */}
        <Image
            alt="Card background"
            className="object-cover rounded-xl"
            src="/patent/1.png"
            height={270}
            width={270}
        />
        {/* </a> */}
    </CardBody>
</Card>
<Modal isOpen={isOpen} onOpenChange={onOpenChange} size="5xl" scrollBehavior="outside" id="modal">
    <ModalContent>
        {() => (
            <>
                <ModalBody>
                    <Image
                        alt="Card background"
                        className="object-cover rounded-xl"
                        src="/patent/1.png"
                        height={2000}
                        width={2000}
                    />
                </ModalBody>
            </>
        )}
    </ModalContent>
</Modal>

My question is, since I have a list of images, whose length is variable. It is not wise or elegant to hard-code a list of corresponding useDisclosure()
How can I auto create useDisclosure for each image?

Problem :

Show full size image in a Modal, by opening a Modal through pressable card

Solution :

You don't need multiple Modal or useDisclosure() hooks, because you can just pass the selected image details to a Modal using a state.

Code :
I have kept code as minimum as possible (you may make necessary changes as needed)
// 'use client' // IF USING NEXTJS UNCOMMENT THIS

import { Card, CardBody, CardHeader, Modal, ModalBody, ModalContent, ModalHeader, useDisclosure } from '@nextui-org/react';
import { useState } from 'react';

const ImgCard = () => {

    const Images = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Gertrude",
        "url": "http://dummyimage.com/1026x1003.png/ff4444/ffffff",
        "date": "08/15/2023"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Steve",
        "url": "http://dummyimage.com/1087x1100.png/5fa2dd/ffffff",
        "date": "08/17/2023"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Beauregard",
        "url": "http://dummyimage.com/1115x1032.png/dddddd/000000",
        "date": "12/21/2023"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Cinderella",
        "url": "http://dummyimage.com/1029x1141.png/cc0000/ffffff",
        "date": "08/14/2023"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Charmain",
        "url": "http://dummyimage.com/1140x1013.png/cc0000/ffffff",
        "date": "12/18/2023"
    }]

    const [ClickedImg, SetClickedImg] = useState(null)
    // STORES OBJECT {}, Image details 
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure();

    return (
        <div className='flex gap-4 '>
            {
                Images.map((v, i) => (
                    <Card className="" isPressable onPress={() => {
                        // SET IMAGE DETAILS
                        SetClickedImg(v)
                        // v = FULL OBJECT { "id": 1, "name": "Gertrude", "url": "http://dummyimage.com/1026x1003.png/ff4444/ffffff", "date": "08/15/2023" } 
                        onOpen()  // THEN OPEN MODAL
                    }}>
                        <CardHeader className="flex-col items-start">
                            <p className="text-tiny uppercase font-bold">{v.id}</p>
                            <small className="text-default-500">{v.date}</small>
                            <h4 className="font-bold text-large">{v.name}</h4>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardBody className="overflow-visible">
                            <img
                                alt="Card background"
                                className="object-cover rounded-xl w-60 h-60"
                                src={v.url}
                            />
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                ))
            }
            <Modal
                isOpen={isOpen} onOpenChange={onOpenChange} size="5xl"
                scrollBehavior="outside" id="modal"
            >
                <ModalContent>
                    {() => (
                        <>
                            {/*  ACCESS DETAILS FROM STATE */}
                            <ModalHeader className="flex flex-col gap-1">{ClickedImg.name}</ModalHeader>
                            <ModalBody>

                                <img
                                    alt="Card background"
                                    className="object-cover rounded-xl"
                                    src={ClickedImg.url}
                                // ACCESS DETAILS FROM STATE
                                />
                            </ModalBody>
                        </>
                    )}
                </ModalContent>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
export default ImgCard

Explaination :

Images array contains object with image details,

const [ClickedImg, SetClickedImg] = useState(null) is used to store clicked image details

Then Card is mapped using Images array, & details are assigned in it. onPress function does two things sets state SetClickedImg(v) & then opens Modal by calling onOpen().

When Card is clicked, Modal opens & shows details using ClickedImg state.

Don't forget to uncomment use client line if using NextJS.



I did something similar, but I’ve refactor in your code. Hope this helps.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Card, CardHeader, CardBody, Modal, ModalContent, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, useDisclosure } from '@nextui-org/react';
enter code here
import Image from 'next/image';

const ImageGallery = ({ images }) => {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure();
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

const handleOpen = (image) => {
    setSelectedImage(image);
    onOpen();
};

return (
    <>
        {images.map((image, index) => (
            <Card key={index} className="" isPressable onPress={() => handleOpen(image)}>
                <CardHeader className="flex-col items-start">
                    <p className="text-tiny uppercase font-bold">id:{image.id}</p>
                    <small className="text-default-500">date:{image.date}</small>
                    <h4 className="font-bold text-large">{image.name}</h4>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody className="overflow-visible">
                    <Image
                        alt="Card background"
                        className="object-cover rounded-xl"
                        src={image.thumbnailSrc}
                        height={270}
                        width={270}
                    />
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        ))}
        {selectedImage && (
            <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onOpenChange={onOpenChange} size="5xl" scrollBehavior="outside" id="modal">
                <ModalContent>
                    {() => (
                        <>
                         <ModalHeader>
                                <h2>{selectedImage.name}</h2>
                            </ModalHeader>
                            <ModalBody>
                                <Image
                                    alt="Card background"
                                    className="object-cover rounded-xl"
                                    src={selectedImage.fullSizeSrc}
                                    height={2000}
                                    width={2000}
                                />
                            </ModalBody>
                            <ModalFooter>
                                <Button onPress={onOpenChange}>Close</Button>
                            </ModalFooter>
                        </>
                    )}
                </ModalContent>
            </Modal>
        )}


       </>
    );
  };

This is an example of how to use.
const images = [
    { 
      id: '', 
      date: '2021', 
      name: 'img1', 
      thumbnailSrc: '/stills/housePlan1.png', 
      fullSizeSrc: '/stills/housePlan2.
    } 
  ];

How to use in your other functions
export default function App() {
    return <ImageGallery images={images} />;
}

